# Windows store certification - error with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am unable to pass Windows app Certification test because of these 2 errors:

```
Package compliance test
FAILED
   MyApp takes a dependency on Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package (Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00) framework but is missing the framework dependency declaration in the manifest.

Supported API test
FAILED
API RoReportUnhandledError in api-ms-win-core-winrt-error-l1-1-1.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLiteWinRT.dll calls this API.
API ??0AccessDeniedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@P$AAVString@1@@Z in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLiteWinRT.dll calls this API.
API ??0COMException@Platform@@Q$AAA@HP$AAVString@1@@Z in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLiteWinRT.dll calls this API.
.....
API malloc in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLiteWinRT.dll calls this API.
API memcpy in msvcr120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. SQLiteWinRT.dll calls this API.
```

Type of the app: Windows Metro
Platform: Windows 8

There I add SQLite project as a reference to my my project.

[image]

Anybody experience same situation ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Windows Store specific library.  See [here](http://sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: I am aware of those DLLs but none of them worked form me. As said I am targeting Windows8 not 8.1 and only oslution that owrked for me were including. Sqlite.cs as separate project and adding reference to that project

Comment: Have you tried the nuget package? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e